# Where is the search queue in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

We know if multiple clients request ES server will caused ES thread pool full, then the new requests will be put in queue. I wanna to know the architecture is `Request->ES Server(Queue->Thread)` or `Request->ES Server(Thread->Queue)`.
In other words is the request would be put at ES queue first and then the ES thread pick it up for operation or ES thread directly accept the request and operate, while the thread pool is full then put the new request to queue.
Or say is queue behind thread or thread behind queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it goes like this.
Elasticsearch has a thread pool queue architecture per module.
A module here can be search  , bulk , index or anything of that sort.
Now lets assume the thread pool size is 4 and size of queue is 20.
When a request comes if there is a free thread in the threadpool , he takes up the work.
And if there are not feed thread in the threadpool , the work get queued in the queue.
Whenever a thread gets free , he comes back and takes up that task.
Now if the queue is full , the task is rejected with a 503 HTTP code.